# Javascript Object.Prototype vs Object.anything

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm trying to wrap my head around the JavaScripts prototype object and after some testing I saw that setting `Object.prototype` to parent `Object.prototype`  or setting it to parent `Object.a` can seemingly yield the same results.

Below is some code to explain this better.

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
Person.a = {};
Person.a.getName = function(){
    return this.name;
}
Person.prototype.getName = function(){
    return this.name;
}
function Male(name) {
    this.gender = "male";
    this.name = name;
    return this;
}
function Female(name) {
    this.gender = 'female';
    this.name = name;
    return this;
}
Male.prototype = Person.a;
Female.prototype = Person.prototype;
var m = new Male("levi");
var f = new Female("cho");
f.getName(); //cho
m.getName(); //levi
```

I think I'm missing a main component of how the prototype object works but I'm not sure what.

Any help would be really greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only magical thing about a constructor "prototype" property is the way it participates in property lookup from an object reference. In every other way, it's just a plain property, and its value is just a plain object.

Comment: @Pointy I see. so each level of inheritance has its own prototype object and its parents prototype object?

Comment: Well it's a *chain* of references.  The exact details get pretty dizzying, but the prototype objects themselves are just ordinary objects, and can be initialized, updated, etc. exactly like any other object. Thus there's nothing really "weird" about `Male.prototype = Person.a` because `Person.a` is a perfectly good object.

Comment: Got it. Thanks! Do you have a good reference you can recommend where I can read up more about prototypes?

Comment: There are some online sources; [here's one that's pretty good, if a little dense](http://blog.vjeux.com/2011/javascript/how-prototypal-inheritance-really-works.html).  In my experience (coming from a C/C++/Java background), I've learned over time that it's really pretty rare that I need to worry about JavaScript inheritance, and I write a **lot** of JavaScript code.

Comment: What you did here is basically :  Male.prototype = { getName : function() {...} }; and after : Female.prototype = { getName : function() { ...same instructions...} }; No wonder you get the same behavior for f and m objects, since you assigned them 'same' prototype ('==', not === ).